# Python: Populate or add value to current value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, addition

I have data in the form of

```
00 154
01 72
02 93
03 202
04 662
05 1297
00 256
```

I wish to go through each line and make the value in column 1 the key and the value of column 2 the value

also if the current key already exists, mathematically add the new value of column  2 to the current value of column 2.

Tried this:

```
search_result = searches.stdout.readlines()
      for output in search_result:
        a,b =  output.split()
        a = a.strip()
        b = b.strip()

        if  d[a]:
         d[a] = d[a] + b
        else:
         d[a] = b
```

And Got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_idmanager_stats.py", line 25, in <module>
    if  d[a]:
KeyError: '00'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `collections.defaultdict` is for.

You can simply do

```
d = defaultdict(int)
```

And

```
d[a]= d[a] + int(b)
```

And you'll find that it works without any `if` statement.

Comment: this is cool, but it doesn't give me the aggregate value for say key 00 instead it gives me multiple rows with key 00

Comment: @Simply Seth: What?  It computes a sum.  Not a list.  What are you talking about?

Comment: I needed to un-indent the print loop one more level ... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for output in search_results:
   a,b = output.split()
   d[int(a)] += int(b)
```